# biztalk server 2010 Error Routiing through SMTP send port

Tags: biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

I have got a simple BizTalk Application in which there is only one schema and pipeline. I have simply add XML Validator in validate stage of pipeline.I have deployed this app in BizTalk Server 2010.

Now I have created a receive location which takes a XML file and set its receive pipeline which i have created. I have also marked "Enable routing for failed messaged" in receive port.

I have also created a SMTP send port and and configured it with mail server name and etc.

Receive port is working fine but send port is unable to send emails. 
When i check "Track Service Instance" is shows an error "Transport failed to connect to the server".

**Update:** I am using Gmail SMTP server name in order to send e-mails and I am getting the error *"The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ye1sm22267001pab.19 - gsmtp"*

Where could be the problem? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

With that error in your update the problem is clear.
The Gmail server is expecting a SSL connection.

See [SMTP TLS problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/daf32122-bfc6-4571-8e38-8c9cb5dc6451/smtp-tls-problem)

> The standard SMTP adapter does not support SSL/TLS connections.
>
> You will need to write a custom adapter or purchase a third party
>   adapter to support SSL connections
>
> http://www.nsoftware.com/products/biztalk/adapters/emails.aspx
>
> Greg.Forsythe

EDIT:  An alternative is to connect to a local SMTP server that doesn't require SSL/TLS  and let it route the e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 32 bit or 64 bit? Is your tracking host in 32 bit or 64 bit?  MIME/SMIME encoder pipeline can't run in 64 bit mode...  are you using that?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634591.aspx

Comment: If you need more info, please leave your questions as a comment question.

Comment: @LisaEdwards Biztalk is running on WIndows server 2008R2 64bit machine. I am not using any encoder pipeline.

Comment: @LisaEdwards I am using gmail smtp server name in order to send mails and i am getting error "The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ye1sm22267001pab.19 - gsmtp"

Comment: are you using SSL?  Gmail requires it unless you uncheck it under the sender email account address settings.

Answer (score 0):

"Transport failed to connect to the server"

This error message basically means the BizTalk SMTP adapter is unable to connect to the SMTP server or the server does not allow to send the e-mail.

Try connecting to the SMTP server with the telnet client (you may need to install this as an additional feature) or by configuring the proxy (available on the SMTP adapter and adapter defaults).

It might also be the case that you need to authenticate towards the SMTP server.
Also, some SMTP servers do not allow to send an e-mail from an unknown domain like "someone@notthenameofthecompany.com".

Hope this helps.